# How do I access the previous model's attributes of JSON file from within a Handlebars Views template?

Tags: json, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have created page with multiple items (using JSON data that is now a Backbone collection) that display like a slideshow.
The data is loading correctly and the page ID is showing in address bar fine. (i.e. localhost:3000/#/articles/plausible-homework-excuses).

However, I want to add arrows so I can go forward or backward in the collection and update the address bar but I can't seem to access the sibling article's ID.

In the view.js file I have created this:

```
var ArticleView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: "ul",
className: "deck",
template: Handlebars.compile(
    '{{#each models}}' +
    '<li class="card-single" id="{{attributes.id}}">' +
    '<div class="card-wrapper">' +
        '<div class="card-control">' +
            '<a class="previous" id="{{attributes.id}}" href="#/articles/{{attributes.id}}">' +
                '<span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>' +
            '</a>' +
            '<div class="card-count">{{attributes.index}}/{{collection.length}}</div>' +
            '<a class="next" id="{{attributes.id}}" href="#/articles/{{attributes.id}}">' +
                '<span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>' +
            '</a>' +
            '</div>' +
        '<div class="content">' +
        '<a href="#">' +
            '<h2>{{attributes.name}}</h2>' +
        '</a> ' +
        '{{{attributes.content}}}' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="bottom-card-control">' +
            '<a class="previous" id="{{attributes.id}}" href="#/articles/{{attributes.id}}">' +
                '<span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>' +
            '</a>' +
            '<a href="" class="share">Share this card</a>' +
            '<a class="next" id="{{attributes.id}}" href="#/articles/{{attributes.id}}">' +
                '<span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>' +
            '</a>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</li>' +
    '{{/each}}' 
),

initialize: function  () {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "reset", this.render);
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "add", this.showItem);
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "remove", this.render);
},
events:  {
    'click .next' : 'showNext',
    'click .previous' : 'showPrev'
},
```

So as you can see from the above, the {{attributes.id}} will pick up the current Model's ID and not its sibling before or after that.

The items are taken from a JSON file that looks like this:

```
[
{
    "id": "plausible-homework-excuses",
    "index": 1,
    "url": "http://www.test.com.",
    "name": "Plausible homework excuses",
    "imagepath": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/",
    "content": "<p>Dog ate my homework is something completely plausible</p>"
},
{
    "id": "the-immediate-political-crisis",
    "index": 2,
    "url": "http://www.test.com",
    "name": "The immediate political crisis",
    "imagepath": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/",
    "content": "<p>Stranger than fiction.</p>"
},
{
    "id": "when-is-it-time-to-let-go",
    "index": 3,
    "url": "http://www.test.com",
    "name": "When is it time to let go",
    "imagepath": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/",
    "content": "<p>When is it time to let go? Don't let your watch let you down.</p>"
 }
]
```

Is there a way of getting {{attributes.id}} to show {{nextsibling.attributes.id}}?

So if I was in an article for "When is it time to let go" and want to click back, the URL will change from "localhost:3000/#/articles/when-is-it-time-to-go" to "localhost:3000/#/articles/the-immediate-political-crisis".

Comment: some quotes lost in json, it that ok?

Comment: You mean for the index values? It shouldn't cause issues cause they are numerical.

Comment: `"id": "the-immediate-political-crisis,`

Comment: i guess a solution maybe in processing more in backbone and parsing in handlebars just prepared pieces since you need to remember a status of current showed item.

Comment: Thanks I have fixed the typo, I was modifying the content for demo purposes.

Comment: So are you saying that I should create variables in the view.js file, sorry I'm quite new to Backbone and not sure where to start to manipulate the handlebar syntax.

Comment: make an model view, incorporate it in a collection view and memorize an item index from the collection you are showing.